# Tool for converting OEIS sequences into Desmos lists

Tags: python, parsing, unit-testing, console, web-scraping

https://github.com/CascadeIllusion/DesmOEIS

Recently began work on a Python project called DesmOEIS to build up my portfolio. It's a simple console program that looks up integer sequences from the OEIS, parses them, and converts them into Desmos lists using the Desmos API.

The program works fine, I just want general feedback to make sure I'm doing things the right way (not just code-wise, but also in terms of project structuring). Unit tests succeeded on my end, but then again maybe I'm not building good unit tests.

**console.py**

```
import sys
import webbrowser
from parsing import *
from desmos import *
from sequence import Sequence


def main():

    intro = \
      "DesmOEIS\n" \
      "A tool for converting OEIS sequences to Desmos lists.\n" \
      "\n" \
      "Type id=<OEIS id> (without the brackets) to convert a sequence. \n" \
      "Type help for a list of all valid commands. \n" \
      "Type exit to close the application. \n" \

    help = \
        "\nSyntax: (Command Name)=(Argument)\n\n" \
        "id: Attempts to convert an OEIS id argument into a Desmos list. \n" \
        "The \"A\" is optional, and trailing zeros may be excluded.\n\n" \
        \
        "name: Assigns the resulting Desmos list to a variable with the given name. \n" \
        "Names must be exactly one letter character (except \"e\"), no numbers or special characters.\n\n" \
        \
        "trim: Filters a list using Python-style slicing syntax. For A:B:C:\n" \
        "A is the starting index (inclusive), default 0.\n" \
        "B is the ending index (exclusive), default is the list length.\n" \
        "C is a step value that is used to skip every C elements, default is 1 (don't skip anything).\n\n" \
        \
        "ext: Pass Y to this to output the extended version of the OEIS sequence.\n" \
        "WARNING: Passing an entire extended sequence this way is usually not a good idea, as such\n" \
        "sequences can be hundreds of elements long, and can cause your browser to hang. You may want\n" \
        "to combine this with trimming syntax to reduce the number of elements.\n\n" \
        \
        "view: Opens the .html file containing the last converted sequence since starting the program. \n" \
        "Does not work if used before converting a sequence.\n\n" \
        \
        "help: View a list of all valid commands.\n\n" \
        \
        "exit: Closes the application." \

    print(intro)

    file = None

    while True:
        cmd = input()

        if cmd == "help":
            print(help)
            continue

        if cmd == "view":
            if file is None:
                print("No sequence converted yet.")
                continue
            webbrowser.open(f"file://{os.path.realpath(file)}")
            continue

        if cmd == "exit":
            sys.exit()

        # Multiple commands are comma separated
        cmds = cmd.split(', ')
        cmds[-1] = cmds[-1].replace(',', '')

        if not cmds[0].startswith("id"):
            print("First argument must be id.")
            continue

        args = dict()

        for i in cmds:
            i = i.split("=")

            cmd = i[0]
            value = i[1]

            args[cmd] = value

        id = parse_id(args)

        results = find_id(id)

        if results:
            sequence = Sequence(id)
            sequence.args = args
            sequence.results = results
        else:
            print("Invalid id.")
            continue

        sequence.integers = parse_integers(sequence)

        name = sequence.args.get("name")

        if name:
            if len(name) > 1:
                print("Variable names must be one character only.")
                continue

            if str.isdecimal(name) or name == 'e':
                print("Numeric names and the constant e (2.71828...) are not allowed.")
                continue

        sequence.name = name

        file = create_expression(sequence, create_desmos_list)

        print("Sequence converted successfully! \n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**parsing.py**

```
import requests


def parse_id(args):

    id = args.get("id")

    # Remove the preceding A if included
    id = id.replace('A', '')

    # Add trailing zeros if necessary
    length = len(id)
    if length < 6:
        for i in range(0, 6 - length):
            id = "0" + id

    # Add A at the beginning of the query
    id = 'A' + id

    return id


def find_id(id):

    url = f"https://oeis.org/search?q=id:{id}&fmt=text"
    r = requests.get(url)

    if "No results." in r.text:
        return None

    return r


def parse_integers(sequence):

    text = sequence.results.text

    text = str.splitlines(text)

    rows = []

    if sequence.args.get("ext") == "Y":

        b_id = sequence.id.replace('A', 'b')
        url = f"https://oeis.org/{sequence.id}/{b_id}.txt"
        r = requests.get(url)
        sequence.results = r
        text = r.text
        text = str.splitlines(text)

        for line in text:
            space = line.find(" ")
            row = line[space + 1:]
            row = row.split(', ')
            rows.append(row)

    else:

        for line in text:
            if line.startswith('%S') or line.startswith('%T') or line.startswith('%U'):
                # integers start 11 characters into the line
                row = line[11:]
                row = row.split(',')
                rows.append(row)

    rows = [row for integer in rows for row in integer]

    # Remove empty elements resulting from commas at the end of the %S and %T rows
    rows = list(filter(None, rows))

    trim = sequence.args.get("trim")

    if trim:
        if ":" not in trim:
            print("Trim argument missing colons ( : ).")
            return
        trim = trim.split(":")
        if not (trim[0] is "" or trim[1] is ""):
            for i in trim:
                if i.isdigit() and trim[0] >= trim[1]:
                    print("Start value must be less than the end value.")
                    return
        if trim[0] is "":
            trim[0] = '0'
        if trim[1] is "":
            trim[1] = len(rows)
        for i in trim:
            i = str(i)
            if not i.isdigit():
                print("Invalid input for trim argument.")
                return
        trim = list(map(int, trim))
        start = trim[0]
        end = trim[1]
        if len(trim) == 3:
            if trim[2] is 0:
                print("Step value cannot be zero.")
                return
            step = trim[2]
            rows = rows[start:end:step]
        else:
            rows = rows[start:end]

    return rows
```

**desmos.py**

```
import os
from sequence import Sequence

def create_expression(sequence, func):

    graph = open("../resources/desmos_graph_base.html")
    graph = graph.read()

    expr = func(sequence)

    # Add another placeholder comment below the expression to allow for further expressions
    graph = graph.replace("<!-- PLACEHOLDER -->", f"{expr} \n <!-- PLACEHOLDER -->")

    sequence.graph = graph

    dir = "../graphs/"
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)
    filename = f"{dir}{sequence.id}.html"
    out_graph = open(filename, "w")
    out_graph.write(graph)

    return filename


def create_desmos_list(sequence):

    integers = sequence.integers

    desmos_list = str(integers)
    desmos_list = desmos_list.replace("'", "")

    name = sequence.name

    if sequence.args.get("name") is not None:
        name = name + "="
    else:
        name = ""

    expr = f"calculator.setExpression({{ id: 'graph1', latex:\"{name}{desmos_list}\" }});"
    return expr
```

**sequence.py**

```
class Sequence():

    def __init__(self, id):
        self._id = id

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @property
    def args(self):
        return self._args

    @args.setter
    def args(self, args):
        self._args = args

    @property
    def integers(self):
        return self._integers

    @integers.setter
    def integers(self, integers):
        self._integers = integers

    @property
    def results(self):
        return self._results

    @results.setter
    def results(self, results):
        self._results = results

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name
```

**test_parsing.py**

```
import unittest
from parsing import *
from sequence import *

"""
# Example sequences used:
http://oeis.org/A000045
http://oeis.org/A000047
http://oeis.org/A139827
"""


class TestIdParsing(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_parse_id(self):
        args = {"id": "A000045"}
        self.assertEqual("A000045", parse_id(args))

    def test_parse_id_no_prefix(self):
        args = {"id": "000045"}
        self.assertEqual("A000045", parse_id(args))

    def test_parse_id_no_trailing_zeros(self):
        args = {"id": "A45"}
        self.assertEqual("A000045", parse_id(args))

    def test_parse_id_no_trailing_zeros_no_prefix(self):
        args = {"id": "45"}
        self.assertEqual("A000045", parse_id(args))

    def test_parse_id_six_digit(self):
        args = {"id": "A139827"}
        self.assertEqual("A139827", parse_id(args))

    def test_parse_id_six_digit_no_prefix(self):
        args = {"id": "139827"}
        self.assertEqual("A139827", parse_id(args))


class TestIdFinding(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_find_id_success(self):
        id = "A000045"
        self.assertNotEqual(None, find_id(id))

    def test_find_id_fail(self):
        id = "A123ABC"
        self.assertEqual(None, find_id(id))


class TestIntegerParsing(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_parse_integers(self):

        args = {"": ""}

        id = "A000045"

        integers = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946,
                    17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578,
                    5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155]

        integers = list(map(str, integers))

        url = f"https://oeis.org/search?q=id:{id}&fmt=text"
        r = requests.get(url)

        sequence = Sequence(id)
        sequence.integers = integers
        sequence.results = r
        sequence.args = args

        self.assertEqual(integers, parse_integers(sequence))

    # Use a different sequence because most extended sequences are too big to reasonably fit
    def test_parse_integers_ext(self):

        args = {"ext": "Y"}

        id = "A000047"

        integers = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 15, 26, 48, 87, 161, 299, 563, 1066, 2030, 3885, 7464, 14384, 27779, 53782, 104359,
                    202838, 394860, 769777, 1502603, 2936519, 5744932, 11249805, 22048769, 43248623, 84894767,
                    166758141, 327770275, 644627310, 1268491353, 2497412741, 4919300031, 9694236886, 19112159929]
        integers = list(map(str, integers))

        url = f"https://oeis.org/search?q=id:{id}&fmt=text"
        r = requests.get(url)

        sequence = Sequence(id)
        sequence.integers = integers
        sequence.results = r
        sequence.args = args

        self.assertEqual(integers, parse_integers(sequence))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Great first question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Line continuations

Multi-line strings like this:

```
intro = \
  "DesmOEIS\n" \
  "A tool for converting OEIS sequences to Desmos lists.\n" \
  "\n" \
  "Type id=<OEIS id> (without the brackets) to convert a sequence. \n" \
  "Type help for a list of all valid commands. \n" \
  "Type exit to close the application. \n" \
```

are better-represented as parenthesized expressions:

```
intro = (
    "DesmOEIS\n" 
    "A tool for converting OEIS sequences to Desmos lists.\n" 
    "\n" 
    "Type id=<OEIS id> (without the brackets) to convert a sequence.\n" 
    "Type help for a list of all valid commands.\n" 
    "Type exit to close the application.\n" 
)
```

Also note that the second level of indentation should be at four spaces and not two.

### Consider case-insensitive commands

It would be easy, and a user quality-of-life improvement, to compare strings against lowered input:

```
cmd = input().lower()
```

If you want to get really fancy you could implement unambiguous prefix string matching, i.e. `hel` would match `help`, but that is more advanced.

### List parsing

Rather than this:

```
    # Multiple commands are comma separated
    cmds = cmd.split(', ')
```

it would be safer to split only on a comma, and then strip every resulting entry.

### Dictionary literals

```
args = dict()
```

can be

```
args = {}
```

### Unpacking

```
        i = i.split("=")

        cmd = i[0]
        value = i[1]
```

can be

```
cmd, value = i.split('=')
```

### Replace or ltrim

```
# Remove the preceding A if included
id = id.replace('A', '')
```

does not do what you say it does. It replaces 'A' *anywhere* in the string. Instead, consider `lstrip('A')` which removes any number of 'A' from the left, or if you want to be more precise, use regular expressions and `'^A'`.

### Character repetition

```
    for i in range(0, 6 - length):
        id = "0" + id
```

can be

```
id = '0'*(6 - length) + id
```

### Requests parameters

```
url = f"https://oeis.org/search?q=id:{id}&fmt=text"
r = requests.get(url)
```

should use a dict argument to `params` instead of baking those into the URL; read
https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

### Requests checking for failure

Call `r.raise_for_status()` after your `get`. Otherwise the failure mode for HTTP requests will be hidden.

### Pathlib

Consider the `pathlib.Path` alternatives to these calls:

```
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)
```

### Setters and getters

This kind of boilerplate:

```
@property
def args(self):
    return self._args

@args.setter
def args(self, args):
    self._args = args
```

is somewhat unpythonic. `_args` is not a strictly private variable by anything other than convention. You are not gaining anything from these properties. Delete them and rename `_args` to `args` if you're going to let users modify this member.

### Unit tests

Great; you have some! Consider mocking away `requests.get` in your tests; otherwise this could not strictly be considered a unit test.

Comment: `id` is a python builtin, so it shouldn't be used as a variable name.  Padding the id with leading zeros can be done with an f-string: `f"{seq_id:0>6s}"`.

Comment: @RootTwo I've never once used `id`, the only time I've seen it used is to explain how `is` is different to `==`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch for your feedback! I'm really glad I asked; I didn't know about some of the syntax tricks like with the unpacking or the character repetition. Also did not know about the request parameters either. Very, very much appreciated!

Comment: @Peilonrayz it was in the original code.  I was adding a comment to Reinderien's answer.